# Is it possible to develop a file label extension for EXPLORER?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop a VSCode Extension for EXPLORER to set label (or tag) for files/directories, so that I can distinguish out them.

[image]

but I searched the Document of VSCode Docs, didn't find a place to introduce this implementation. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: you can add commands to the explorer context menu and buttons on hover, you can't change the UI with additional  widgets, if you want that you have to write a replacement using WebviewView but you lose the File icon feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for the [FileDecoration API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileDecoration).

It allows you to define `badge`, `color` and `tooltip` for files and folders.

Based on your mockup, I guess this API would work just fine. Unless you need to have more than 2 characters for the `badge` attribute, which is not possible, today.

##### Update / Sample

Here is a small sample. It will add a smile emoji at the right side of every file/folder (because I'm ignoring `Uri`) and make the file/folder to be colored as `problemsWarningIcon.foreground`.

The *color* is where I think the API *maybe* doesn't work perfect for you, because it will be applied to the file/folder too, not only the `badge`. If this doesn't fit your needs, you need to open a feature request in VS Code repo asking for changes

```js
class EmojiFileDecorationProvider implements vscode.FileDecorationProvider{
    onDidChangeFileDecorations?: vscode.Event<vscode.Uri | vscode.Uri[] | undefined> | undefined;
    provideFileDecoration(uri: vscode.Uri, token: vscode.CancellationToken): vscode.ProviderResult<vscode.FileDecoration> {
        return new vscode.FileDecoration("", "tooltip smile", new vscode.ThemeColor("problemsWarningIcon.foreground"));
    }
}


export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    ...
    vscode.window.registerFileDecorationProvider(new EmojiFileDecorationProvider());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any example code for FileDecoration?

Comment: Answer updated with a sample and additional info.